# Showing duplicate keys in associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have an array of numbers:

*[Note: $arrNum is dynamic. It's created using rand(). So every time the values will be different. It's not fixed values.]*

```
$arrNum = [2, 5, 6, 6, 8];
```

Now there'll will be an associative array named $arrNumDouble. The key of $arrNumDouble is the value of $arrNum and the value corresponding to the key is the double of the key.

```
$arrNumDouble = [];

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($arrNum); $i++) {

    if (array_key_exists($arrNum[$i], $arrNumDouble)) {

        //repeated values in the $arrNum array, the 
        //key in the $arrNumDouble array is 
         //supplemented with a letter, e.g. “A”

        $arrNumDouble[$arrNum[$i]."A"] = $arrNum[$i] * 2;
    } else {
        $arrNumDouble[$arrNum[$i]] = $arrNum[$i] * 2;
    }    
};
```

Now $arrNumDouble becomes:

```
$arrNumDouble = array
                (
                  [2] => 4,
                  [5] => 10,
                  [6] => 12,
                  [6A] => 12,
                  [8] => 16
                 )
```

From this $arrNumDouble I can easily display on screen like this:

```
<?php foreach($arrNumDouble as $key => $value): ?>
       <tr>
           <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
       </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

Num    Double
2        4
5        10
6        12
6A       12
8        16
```

**But how can I display like this:**

```
Num    Double
2        4
5        10
6        12
6        12   //without letter A
8        16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store results as array of arrays as approach:

```
<?php
$arrNum = [2, 5, 6, 6, 8];

$arrNumDouble = array_map(
    function($el) {
        return [$el, 2*$el];
    },
    $arrNum
);

#var_export($arrNumDouble);

foreach($arrNumDouble as $el) {
    echo "2 * $el[0] = $el[1]" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[share PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=0cebae0f0bc7f2bb4d887dbde50ef166&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 1):

use intVal to remove the A char and keep number:

```
<?php foreach($arrNumDouble as $key => $value): ?>
       <tr>
           <td><?php echo intVal($key); ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
       </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the associative arrays for this purpose!

However the simplest method is to convert your string '6A' into a number with intval(string) PHP function.

intval("6A") returns 6